Looking for a Spanish Dictionary BGL file for GoldenDict
I'm trying to find a Spanish dictionary in BGL format for GoldenDict. While I know official sources might not be available, I was hoping the community could point me in the right direction.
Does anyone have a trusted source for Spanish BGL dictionaries?
Are there any alternatives for offline Spanish dictionaries in GoldenDict?
Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

https://freedict.org/downloads/
http://www.goldendict.org/dictionaries.php
http://www.babylon.com/gloss/glossaries.php
"
Babylon (.bgl) dictionaries
Those can be downloaded here, from the official Babylon site. If instead of .bgl files you are getting .exe installers, use 7Zip to extract them (use full version of 7Zip, the one which supports CAB files). The .bgl files would be inside.
Some dictionaries are free, some are provided on a try-and-buy basis. We encourage you to buy them after you've tried them if you've decided you're going to keep using them.
"
